# Persistently fix the height of a split in vim

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, neovim, split

So I searched the web far and wide and I can not for the life of me figure out how to do this.

I have the following key binding:

`nnoremap <leader>o :below 10sp term://.//$SHELL <cr> :set winfixheight <cr> i`

Which works initially and if I open horizontal splits above the `:term` but if I open anything below the `:term`, `fzf` for example the `:term` resizes once I close the `fzf` window.

I know the above is a bit difficult to understand so I have attached a gif trying to demonstrate.

[image]

Comment: have you tried something with autocommands ? see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html

Comment: @Nobe4 I have used `autocmd` before but I am not sure how I would use them is this case?

Comment: My first guess would be to trigger a custom function on each resizing (e.g. `WinEnter`, `WinLeave`, but others may be more suitable) that apply `:resize 60` to the desired split. Or maybe with the `'winheight'` option.

Comment: Hey @Nobe4 any idea how I would target that window/split specifically I have looked at setting a custom ID but I can't quite seem to get it working.

Comment: Not a true solution, and won't apply in all cases, but I find myself reflexively doing `<C-a>_` from the  split you want to fix. Resolves the issue for me, but would love a real solution, so I wouldn't have to do this.

Comment: Try changing it to `setlocal winfixwidth winfixheight`

Comment: Does this problem still exist?